# F# TypeInitializationException

Tags: compiler-errors, f#

I stumbled upon a weird runtime error in my code.

The code base is rather big so it is hard to post it here.

but my problem is, I have made a search tree data structure which is used to find specific "words" in a sequence of items in near-linear time. I have tested it and it does not have any error.

I use it in a toy lexer to find the longest matching tokenpattern from a start index in a sequence.

When I try to run (debug/release) build for the code to test it, it throws a TypeInitializationException if I include the word "is" with a DU case IS and, the same for "&" with AND, and the same for "(" with LP, LPar and so forth.

I have tried to rearrange the case position of the tags for the Distriminated union, only including the trubling "word, tag" patterns and it still throw the exceptions. if I change the tag it works fine, but only for some tags.

If I run the same code in interpret mode it runs without any error, which for me seems to be an indication that there must be some weird stuff happening in the compiler phases.

Comment: There's a chance that providing the full exception might help. I'd also suggest removing things from your code until you can get to the least code required to cause the exception. Then you could provide that as a minimal but complete reproducible example.

Comment: I have tried removing code and error handling. I think it might has comes down to the number of cases a discriminated union can have in the F# compiler can take. tried for fun changing it to an enum type instead and it fixed it.

Comment: I'm curious, how many cases do you have?

Comment: it is the second time I encounter it. but fixed it by removing [<Struct>] from a many cases DU.. apparently the way F# implement it there is an upper limit to cases when in struct from because F# does not use the optimal representation for DU where an instance uses tag size + maximum trailing data size..